# Wants to create an application storing data in memory. But i dont want the data to be lost even if my app crashes

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

Wants to create an application storing data in memory. But i dont want the data to be lost even if my app crashes. 
What concept should i use?
Should I use a shared memory, or is there some other concept that suits my requirement better.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: use `mysql` or some other database.

Comment: Persisting the data regularly in a file on disk would help.

Comment: Dumping the data in database or a file will make the application slow. Moreover, I am thinking if i use shared memory or something like that, I can restart my application and it can resume work from the same point and I dont have to write any logic for recovery of the data.

Comment: @user3131441 not really if u do that periodically just to save changes to your data and while it would not restore the latest information it would at least restore some of it to the last save point

Comment: Can you have a thread that does it in parallel periodically asynchronously ?

Comment: what sort of data is it btw ?

Comment: STLs. Mainly vectors

Comment: What kind of data you need to store?

Comment: What kind of application is it?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) (or even orthogonal persistence) and/or for [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing).

This is not possible (at least thru portable C++ code) in the general case for some arbitrary existing C++ code, e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), because of pointers on -or to- the local [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), because of multi-[threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29), and because of external resources (sockets, opened files, ...), because the current [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) cannot be accessed, restored and handled in standard C++.

However, you might *design* your application with persistence in mind. This is a strong architectural requirement. You could for instance have every class contain some dumping method and its load factory function. Beware of shared pointers, and take into account that you could have cyclic references. Study [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) algorithms (e.g. in the [Gc HandBook](http://gchandbook.org/)) which are similar to those needed for persistence (a copying GC is quite similar to a checkpointing algorithm).

Look also in [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) libraries (like [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/)). You might also consider persisting into textual format (e.g. [JSON](http://json.org/)), perhaps inside some [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database (or some real database like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/)....). I am doing this (in C) in my [monimelt](http://github.com/bstarynk/monimelt) software.

You might also consider checkpointing libraries like [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/CLaSS/research/BLCR/)

The important thing is to **think about persistence & checkpointing very *early* at design time**. Thinking of your application as some specialized [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) interpreter or VM might help (notably if you want to persist continuations, or some form of "call stack").

You could fork your process (assuming you are on Linux or Posix) before persistence. Hence, persistence time does not matter that much (e.g. if you persist every hour or every ten minutes).

Some language implementations are able to persist their entire state (notably their heap), e.g. [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) (a good Common Lisp implementation) with its [`save-lisp-and-die`](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Saving-a-Core-Image), or [Poly/ML](http://www.polyml.org/) -an ML dialect- with its [SaveState](http://www.polyml.org/docs/SaveState.html), or [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/) (a [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) implementation).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182961/841108) & [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14545665/841108). J.Pitrat's blog has a related entry: [CAIA as a sleeping beauty](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/05/caia-a-sleeping-beauty/).

Persistency of data with code (e.g. [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) of objects, function pointers) might be technically difficult. [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) -with `dlsym`- might help (and, if you are able to code *machine-specific* things, consider the old [getcontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html), but I don't recommend that). Avoid [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) (for `dlsym`) by declaring `extern "C"` all code related to persistence. If you want to persist some data and be able to restart from it with a slightly modified program (e.g. a small bugfix) things are much more complex.

More pragmatically, you could have a class representing your entire persistable state, and implement methods to persist (and reload it). You would then persist only at certain steps of your algorithm (e.g. if you have a main loop or an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), at start of that loop). You probably don't want to persist too often (e.g. because of the time and disk space required to persist), e.g. perhaps every ten minutes. You might perhaps consider some [transaction log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log) if it fits in the overall picture of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use memory mapped files - `mmap` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) And allocate all your structures inside mapped memory region. System will properly save mapped file to disk when your app crashes.

Comment: Probably won't work because of ASLR, and because most standard C++ containers allocate data outside of that region.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch we can use custom allocators or use plain `C` arrays t all. What kind of data we need to store? It can be nice `C++ template` solution :)

Comment: Then every container template should be used with an application specific allocator.